# What is wrong with the SQL Syntax in this PHP code?

Tags: php, mysqli

I am learning PHP so I was practicing SQL and CRUD in PHP however I seem to have an issue but I don't see what is wrong. There are two files:

databases.php

```
<?php
// 1. Create a database connection
$dbhost = "localhost";
$dbuser = "root";
$dbpass = "root";
$dbname = "widget_corp";
$connection = mysqli_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass, $dbname);
// Test if connection occured
if(mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    die("Database connection failed: " .
        mysqli_connect_error() . 
            " (" . mysqli_connect_errno() . ")"
);
}

?>
<?php
// Perform database query
$query = "SELECT * ";
$query .= "FROM subjects ";
$query .= "WHERE visible = 1 ";
$query .= "ORDER BY position ASC";
$result = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
// Test if there was a query error
if (!$result) {
    die("Database query failed.");
}

?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C/DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">

<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Databases</title>
    <body>
        <ul>
        <?php
        // 3. Use returned data (if any)
        while($subject = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
            // Output data from each row
            ?>
            <li><?php echo $subject["menu_name"] . " (" .$subject["id"] . ")"; ?></li>
            <?php
        }
        ?>
    </ul>
        <?php
        // 4. Release returned data
        mysqli_free_result($result);
        ?>
    </body>
<?php
// Close database connection
mysqli_close($connection);  
?>
```

and databases_update.php

```
<?php
// 1. Create a database connection
$dbhost = "localhost";
$dbuser = "root";
$dbpass = "root";
$dbname = "widget_corp";
$connection = mysqli_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass, $dbname);
// Test if connection occured
if(mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    die("Database connection failed: " .
        mysqli_connect_error() . 
            " (" . mysqli_connect_errno() . ")"
);
}

?>
<?php
// Often these are form values in $_POST
$id = 5;
$menu_name = "Delete me";
$position = 4;
$visible = 1;

// 2. Perform database query
$query  = "UPDATE subjects SET ";
$query .= "menu_name = '{$menu_name}', ";
$query .= "position = {$position}, ";
$query .= "visible = {$visible}, ";
$query .= "WHERE id = {$id}";

$result = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
// Test if there was a query error
if ($result) {
    // Success
    // redirect_to("somepage.php");
    echo "Success!";
} else {
    // Failure
    // message = "Subject creation failed";
    die("Database query failed. " . mysqli_error($connection));
}

?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C/DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">

<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Databases</title>
    <body>

    </body>
<?php
// Close database connection
mysqli_close($connection);  
?>
```

The error I am receiving is when I go to localhost:8888/databases_update.php.
This is the error: 
`Database query failed. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE id = 5' at line 1`
What is causing this?

Comment: Lose the comma after `visible = {$visible},`

Comment: You have a comma after `{$visible}`.

Comment: You should be using prepared statements. Don't put variables directly into your query if you can help it.

Comment: And please don't use form POST data in that way.. Escape it first (or even better, use prepared statements!) Google "SQL Injection" http://xkcd.com/327/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer by Wallyk is correct. However it would be better (safer!) to use prepared statements as they prevent SQL injection by improper escaping.

What you then need to do is use the mysqli_prepare function (or $connection->prepare()), then bind the required parameters to the query, and execute it. Like so:

Replace:

```
$query  = "UPDATE subjects SET ";
$query .= "menu_name = '{$menu_name}', ";
$query .= "position = {$position}, ";
$query .= "visible = {$visible}, ";
$query .= "WHERE id = {$id}";
$result = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
```

With:

```
$query = $connection->prepare("UPDATE subjects SET menu_name=?, position=?, visible=? WHERE id=?");
$query->bind_param('siii', $menu_name, $position, $visible, $id); // siii means 1 string, followed by 3 integer values
$result = $query->execute(); // actually run the query
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$query .= "visible = {$visible}, ";
$query .= "WHERE id = {$id}";
```

is the problem where there is a comma preceding the "WHERE" keyword.

```
visible = {$visible}, WHERE id = {$id}
```